# How to check battery consumption caused by Bluetooth Scans

Tags: android, bluetooth, ibeacon-android

I have an Android application to detect Eddystone beacons using the Android Beacon Library. I would like to test the battery consumption caused by the application to find the optimal background and foreground scan rates. In Settings > Apps > MyBeaconDetectorApp, it shows 0% battery usage after having the bluetooth On for more than an hour. I think the application is in background and hence it is 0%. However, how do I check the battery consumption caused by Bluetooth scans. I have set my BackgroundBetweenScanPeriod as 1 minute.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it is difficult to measure the battery consumption directly, here is the technique I use:

1. Use a test device with a limited number of apps installed that will be running in the background.  A stock Nexus device after factory reset is ideal.
2. Charge the battery to 100%
3. Put the device into airplane mode and put bluetooth on.
4. Install your app start it running in the background.  Turn off the screen, and disconnect the device's USB connector.
5. Note the start time.
6. Let the app run in the background for at least 8 hours, ideally in the presence of at least one beacon.
7. Measure the battery level.  The delta from 100% is the percentage drain.  Note this number and the end time.
8. Look up how many mAH your battery has for your phone model.  Multiply the percentage drain by the mAH and divide by the time of the test in hours.  This tells you how many mA the phone uses when running your app.

Next, uninstall your app, and repeat the procedure above.  This will give you a baseline battery drain for your device *without* your app running.

Finally, subtract the mAH baseline from the mAH with your app running to measure the additional mAH used by your app.

One final note:  if you are really scanning every minute in the background (the default is every five minutes to save battery), I would expect this may cause a significant additional battery drain.  Testing using the procedure above will tell you for sure.  I'd love to hear your results!

Comment: I will definitely try this. I was planning to use an online service, maybe AWS Device Farm to achieve this. However, I cannot ask to introduce beacons in their testing centers. Do you think not having a beacon nearby will affect the battery consumption?

Comment: Yes, not having a beacon nearby will affect it in two ways:  (1) If testing on Android 5+, hardware filters are used to minimize battery drain when no beacons are around, but are not used when beacons are around, falling back instead to periodic scanning.  (2)  When beacons are around, it takes a small, but not insignificant amount of CPU to parse the identifiers out of the packets.

Comment: I understood the method however how about relative calculation? Suppose that without app my cellphone (which has 3000mAh) consumed 600 mA in 1 hour and with the app 900 mA was consumed. Can I say 900/600 = 1.5 (50% more energy was consumed)? It's weird because in my calculations the difference in the battery energy was only 10%. (In first case battery SoC was 80%, second case 70%)

Comment: Lots of things may affect these tests besides Bluetooth and it is very hard to control conditions.  Turn off all network connectivity.   Also , consider that your app may also use battery for CPU functions unrelated to Bluetooth