# How does the battery drain in Android when the phone search others?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, battery

I will make the app about searching periodically with a bluetooth in Android.

The app is operating in background and the period may be too short, about 1 min.

but i dont know how I decide that.

I heard the energy with bluetooth gets low.

So. I want the quantitative data about searching with bluetooth.
Or approximate data, fine.

Plz give a hand to set the period.

Comment: Possible duplicate. See here for similar question and answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753978/how-to-check-battery-consumption-caused-by-bluetooth-scans

Comment: Thx a lot. How did you find it fast like this? but i want the data without my experiences, if not.. i have to do...